# Is where any performance difference between using text and integer & in-app constant "type" column in MySQL & php?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, constants

In my case, I have a table which stores a collection of records with similar information but each with unique type column, used in various parts of my application. I know, I know this is "micro-optimisation" but it it an integral part of my application (it will store many records), and I would like it to be optimised, and I am also simply curious, is is faster to use text type and select it like
    SELECT ... WHERE type = 'some_type' 
or use a PHP defined constant like
    const SOMETYPE = 1;
    run_query('SELECT ... WHERE type = '.SOMETYPE);
?

Comment: In an intepreted language like php, the CONSTANT is replaced each time you run the code and then the optimisation is not so good.  On benchmark it could be a lot of reasons why doesn't really matter, like how many queries per second will you run or your server optimization, etc.

Comment: And we need to know if the are declared like "define()" or like "const Constant"

Comment: @Marx The constants are defined second method using const NAME = value

Comment: All depends on you hardware, you need to think about how much payload your queries will get with constants.

Comment: faster != optimized. There's a lot of place where you can look to optimize such as the db indexing, cache size, clustering, logging slow query, deciding whether an operation should be done in php or the db, clustering, load balancing, connection pooling, query optimization... etc. Although I agree constant can be a bit slower, but in most cases they dont differ that much.

Answer (score 1):

The dominant time spent in any query is in fetching rows to work with.  Functions, string vs int, etc, make only minor differences in performance.  Focus on what is clean for your code, and what minimizes the number of rows touched.

Once you have done that, minimize the number of round trips to the server.  Even so, I have created many web pages that do 20-50 queries (each well optimized); the page performance is adequate.

You could also consider the `ENUM` data type.

```
sex ENUM('unk', 'male', 'female') NOT NULL
```

gives you `WHERE sex = 'male'`, implemented as a 1-byte integer under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison will always be slower than integer comparison. Typically, what is done is the string are stored in a separate table, perhaps called `standard_types` or whatever makes sense for the "constants" being stored. That table then has a unique id field that can be referenced by other tables.

This way if you need the strings for reporting, the reporting queries can join to the "types" table for the display strings. Ideally, in my opinion, the id values should reflect a standard numbers that can be expressed as enum values or constants in client code; this minimizes the dependence on the "types" table for non-reporting queries.

Some might argue against keeping the list of standard id values and their meanings coordinated across the database and one or more application codebases; but the alternative is coordinating standard strings across all that (domains that can handle those string values quite differently).

Comment: @Uuerdo please clarify. so do you mean what it wont make any noticeable difference in perfirmance ever if I use string type within db or numeric type wuthin db and refer to them in PHP  using constants ??

Comment: No, I am saying numeric types are almost always faster, whether they are constants or not does not matter. I was just saying you can get the best of both worlds to a degree by storing the strings once in a separate lookup table, and referencing them by a numeric id; so that the actual linking happens on the numeric id values for those strings; and if the id values are known ahead of time, by being enum or constant values on the client side; the string never has to be directly referenced.